# What pole is closer to the galactic edge?

Tags: galaxy, milky-way

Suppose 2 spaceships leave from the earth's north and South Pole going straight up which one will exit the galaxy first (assume they have the same speed and are going in a totally straight line) ? Edge of the galaxy means absence of stars, this question refers to the up-down edge of this spiral galaxy.
The question is about the current distance from the earths poles to the edge (top/down) not to the galactic plane, as far as I understand after crossing the plane the nearest pole to the edge will be reversed.

Comment: Given the kind of distances involved, you can treat the Earth as a mathematical point without any loss of accuracy in the answer.  Now, do you want "edges" in the spiral plane, or perpendicular to that?

Comment: You might like to [edit] your question to be a bit more precise. How do you define “edge”? Are you including the dark matter halo? Are you ignoring gravitational effects (both boosts and “drag”)? Ie is this about simple straight-line distance, or plotting an escape arc?

Comment: Edited to show the question requires a simple straight line, and edge means perpendicular

Comment: and our solar system is at a large angle to the ecliptic plane (https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/orientation-of-the-earth-sun-and-solar-system-in-the-milky-way.888643/) so to get to the edge, you don't want to exit via the pole but at ~27deg from the equator.

Comment: take into consideration the angle... the exit is from the pole

Comment: exiting from the pole gives a much longer trajectory than exiting perpendicular to the galactic plane.

Comment: yes it does... and I am interested in this situation which line would be longer.. from the south or from the north pole

Comment: @hobbes - but since the North and South poles are perpendicular, the angle relative to the galaxy does not affect which one "wins the race"

Comment: In case it's not clear from the answers on the question linked by Hobbes, we are currently  "north" of the galactic plane.

Comment: 60° from south to north by system planetary to the galaxy plane,  and 23° south to north by earth in the planetary system, obvious south pole, but real question which direction sun has?

Comment: what does "north" of the galactic plane mean? We are above the galactic plane and the earth's north pole is pointing away from it?